# Gradle error while executing the build

Tags: android, build, gradle

I am getting the following error.

`Error:org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileSnapshotter$FileCollectionSnapshotImpl` cannot be cast to

`org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.OutputFilesSnapshotter$OutputFilesSnapshot`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused if your gradle dependency cache is corrupted. To solve this simply go to the terminal and type the following command:

```
gradlew -C rebuild
```

this solved my issue, I hope it helps someone else aswell.